# Getting data ordered following an order according to an array

Tags: php, mysql

I got an array with ids like :

```
$array = array('1234','3214','8764','8467'2364','1113')
```

and what I do to retrieve the items data is to use the IN statement, like :

```
...product_id IN ('.$array .')...
```

The problem is that the data I get is given with an order which I don't know (e.g 8467,2364,3214,1234...).

Is there any way to get the data from mysql following the order provided in the array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to favorite your own questions to get notifications for it, as the poster, you automatically get notifications. The star means "favorite" and it has zero meaning for score or visibility :)

Answer (score 1):

Use order clause like,

```
$oderFields = implode(",",$array);
SELECT....ORDER BY field(product_id, $oderFields);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use [**`implode`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to your array so you will have as string which you can use in your query

```
$array = array('1234','3214','8764','8467','2364','1113');
$string = implode(",", $array);
echo $string;
```

this will output

```
1234,3214,8764,8467,2364,1113
```

Now you can use this string in your query

```
product_id IN ('.$string.')
```

Which will be

```
product_id IN (1234,3214,8764,8467,2364,1113)
```